# How do I remove one string from a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to remove one string from a list of strings (some are identical strings). For example in the list [hello, world, world, hello hello], I would like to remove one of the hello's at random. How would I do this?

P.S. In this situation I do not know the position of any of the 'hello' strings in the list

Comment: Hi Dhar_! `import random; list.remove(random.choice(list))`

Comment: @Artemiy will this remove any random string from the list? I'm looking to remove one of the 'hello' strings at random, not any other strings in the list

Comment: Why at random? Why not just the first one?

Comment: How would I do that? The main thing I am trying to achieve is to have one of the identical strings removed @Alexander

Comment: `my_list = [...];my_list.remove('hello')` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html Also, if you just want to remove duplicates, convert the list to a set and then back to a list, e.g. `list(set(my_list))`.

Comment: "I would like to remove one of the hello's at random" How do you know that you want to remove a "hello", and not a "world"? What problem do you solve by doing this?

Answer (score 5):

```
original = ['hello', 'world', 'world', 'hello', 'hello']
hello_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(original) if x == 'hello']
del original[random.choice(hello_indices)]
```